# Are database queries created using WordPress filters protected from SQL injection?

Tags: query, mysql, sql

I'm using the WordPress 'posts_where' filter (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) to alter my queries as below:

```
        function filter_my_search($where=''){
            global $wpdb;

        if(isset($_GET['q'])) {

            $where .= 'AND (((' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE "%'.$_GET["q"].'%") OR (' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_content LIKE "%'.$_GET["q"].'%")))';
        }
        return $where;
    }
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_my_search');
```

So a query is being run, and I'm intercepting the where clause, and adding an extra condition. Would that code be susceptible to SQL injection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No! WordPress will **not** protect against SQL injection in this case. You need to do so yourself, using `$wpdb->esc_like` and `$wpdb->prepare`:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) ) {    
    // WordPress forces magic quotes (god knows why), unslash it
    $value = wp_unslash( ( string ) $_GET['q'] );

    // Escape like wildcards so that MySQL interprets them as literals
    $value = $wpdb->esc_like( $value );

    // Create our "true" like query
    $value = "%$value%";

    // Now inject it safely
    $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
        " AND ( ( $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s ) OR ( $wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE %s ) )",
        $value,
        $value
    );
}
```

Comment: I see, would you have to do anything similar for functions such as update_post_meta, or was the above necessary because I was specifically writing MySQL clauses?

Comment: No, yep :) Always escape when writing SQL, whereas any core WordPress function that writes to the db will escape the arguments for you.